# Estimated time to update 5 million records in db2

Tags: performance, db2, sql-update

```
I have table Customer_address_tx having structure below..

cust_id_pk      BIGINT
comm_fk         BIGINT
```

**`Now I want to update comm_fk with null where comm_fk is zero, Such records lies in range 280000000 to 320000000(cust_id_pk)`**

In above range, there are 5 million such records having comm_fk=0 which i want to update with null

```
My Update query
```

**db2 "update Customer_address_tx  set comm_fk=null where comm_fk =0"**

In order to run above query effectively, I broke above update statement into multiple update statements according to range 280000000 to 320000000(cust_id_pk) for each **5000**

**db2 "update Customer_address_tx  set comm_fk=null where comm_fk =0 and cust_id_pk between 280000000 and 280005000"**

**db2 "update Customer_address_tx  set comm_fk=null where comm_fk =0 and cust_id_pk between 280005001 and 280010000"**

**. . . .**

Is above right approach..?

Any other approach is welcome...

Comment: edited lakhs to normal notation so the question is more accessible

Comment: 5,000 at a time is a reasonable number.  Are you doing a commit after each update of 5,000?

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc yes i commit after each update of 5000 records.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc what do u think how much time it will take.....as there will be 8000 such update statements

Comment: @rohit: Without knowing what machine you're running this on, nor the load on your DB2 subsystem, my guess would be between 2 and 3 hours.

Comment: i run AIX/64 bit, db2level 9.5, Around 40GB of Ram